# Immer error when using redux/toolkit with React-Native (iOS)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux-toolkit, immer.js

I'm trying to use `@redux/toolkit` in my react-native app. However, when I run the iOS simulator I get the following error.

Metro has encountered an error: While trying to resolve module `immer` from file `/path-node-modules/node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/redux-toolkit.cjs.production.min.js`, the package `/path-node-modules//node_modules/immer/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/path-node-modules/node_modules/immer/dist/immer.esm.mjs`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

- `/path-node-modules/node_modules/immer/dist/immer.esm.mjs(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)`
- `/path-node-modules/node_modules/immer/dist/immer.esm.mjs/index(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)`

I found a [similar issue on immer's github repo](https://github.com/immerjs/immer/issues/331) that was resolved in 2019, but I'm still seeing this today (which is weird because I have all the latest packages).

I edited the node-modules path, because it starts from my root directory.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue. I too have modified my project structure. I guess it is because of modifying the structure because I tried it with a fresh project. There it runs without any issue.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like adding `mjs` to the metro config did the trick.

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("expo/metro-config");

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

defaultConfig.resolver.sourceExts = ['jsx', 'js', 'ts', 'tsx', 'mjs'];

module.exports = defaultConfig;
```

Comment: This exactly fixed the issue. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Thank you! This fixes the issue for "immer": "10.0.2" (no other solutions worked for me)

Answer (score 1):

The answer that @ashish provided got me most of the way there but explicitly replacing the `sourceExts` broke something else in the way things work with `expo`.

So here's an alternative way to add `mjs` to the to the metro config that doesn't alter the existing `defaultConfig`:

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

defaultConfig.resolver.sourceExts.push('mjs');

module.exports = defaultConfig;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just installed version of 9.0.12 for Immer and it fixed!
I guess there is issue in version of 9.0.13.

Answer (score 0):

if you use yarn, put this in your `package.json`:

```json
  "resolutions": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit/**/immer": "9.0.12"
  },
```

and do `yarn install --force`.